# Identifying which Algorithm is which and explaining the running times

Tags: algorithm, big-o

For a given problem with input size **n**, Algorithms A,B,C are executed. In terms of running time, one of the algorithms is **O(n)**, one **O(nlogn)** and one **O(n^2)**. Some measured running times of these algorithms are given below

```
                            Input Size
                    512         1024            2048

            A        70          134             262 
            B        135         517             2053
            C        42          86              182
```

Identify which algorithm is which and explain the observed running times. Which algorithm would you select for different values of **n**

Please help me with the above question.
Thanks

Comment: Homework help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Answer (score 2):

Look at the quotients of the input sizes and the computing times.

Answer (score 1):

Graph the performance of the three algorithms - the time complexity will then become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand the terms `nlogn`, `n^2` and `n`. Consider plotting this functions to understand the relationship between input and their output. The answer will be obvious if you understand these relationships.

Answer (score 1):

This is what their plot would look like

[image]

Now if you understand what [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) implies and how the graphs of **n**, **n<sup>2</sup>** and **nlogn** would look like, it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Graph A : nlogn
Graph B : n2
Graph C : n

Comment: Well I think my answer is confirmed by http://science.slc.edu/~jmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/sorting.gif
right..??

Comment: It looks like A follows the input pretty linearly, while C just jumps ahead, suggesting a multiplier to n.

Answer (score 1):

Often times, I have found that the easiest way to compare complexities was to "normalize" the results.

```
Input Size:      1       2      4
Algorithm A:     1      1.91   3.74
Algorithm C:     1      2.04   4.33
Algorithm B:     1      3.82  15.21
```

This table is simply obtained by divising each line by its minimum (the first element in this case).

I have then re-ordered the lines from the slow-growing one to the fast-growing one: can you guess the complexity of each of the algorithms ?

PS: the cheat sheet for `n log n`, just to verify the approximations

```
Input Size       Time
n                n log n
2*n              2 * n * (log n + log 2)
4*n              4 * n * (log n + 2 * log 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question leaves me surprised: that there are teachers who ask such kind of bogus and misleading questions.

1) Did the question really talk about O(n), O(nlogn), O(n^2) when they really mean Theta(n), Theta(nlogn) and Theta(n^2)?

2)

Just three data points (or 9 total) is not sufficient to distinguish which is which.

We can choose the appropriate constants so that A,B,C could be any of the three we want.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graphs of the 3 dataset. Compare with the growth rate of the graphs for n, nlogn...
You will see.